# What are the potential vulnerabilities with containerized rootless Chrome and --no-sandbox?

Tags: chrome, container, chromium

I'm evaluating running Chromium without native sandboxing in a rootless container. A few points:

- You can containerize Chrome using rootless containers with something like `podman`. This will utilize kernel user-namespaces to isolate the Chrome process.
- Chrome also contains a sandbox mode which is enabled by default.
- User-namespaces make processes think they're root, while running in kernel namespace-isolation.
- Chrome, running as root, requires you to use the `--no-sandbox` flag which is *required* in rootless container.

To what degree, if any does `--no-sandbox` make Chrome less secure, when compared to a rootless container?